# setInitialFileName is not working in jdk 1.7.0 update 25

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, java-7

setInitialFileName is not working in jdk 1.7.0 update 25 but it is working in other versions like 1.7.0 update 45 and update 55. Someone please help me with some common method to set the file name that works in all the updates in jdk 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method which sets the initial filename for all versions of JDK 1.7.

The set initial filename feature was only implemented for Java 1.7 update 40+.

See [RT-16111 "FileChooser: Need to be able to specify initial file name in save dialog"](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-16111) for more details.